# How to remove the first argument of function?

Tags: javascript, arguments

If I have a function I can forward all its arguments with the `arguments` variable.

Now I have a function that needs one (the first) argument for itself and should only forward the rest.

For example:

```
var calledFunction = function(num){
    //do something with num
    //remove num from the arguments
    forwardFunction(arguments);
}
```

I already tried `arguments.shift();` but arguments is only a "Array-like object" and therefore doesn't know the `shift()` function.

**How to remove the first argument from the arguments and forward the rest of the series of arguments?**

Comment: In my projects for school, I was able to just turn the Arguments object into an array to process it. It's been awhile since I've written JS though, so I can't remember exactly how I did it. Shouldn't be that hard though.

Comment: Would you like to pass each element `1..n` of `arguments` as an individual argument, or to pass an array containing elements in position `1..n`?

Comment: Every argument as an individual argument.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In ES6, the idiomatic way to write this would be

```
var calledFunction = function(num, ...args) {
  //do something with num
  forwardFunction(...args);
}
```

Comment: or just `forwardFunction(args)` if the target function does happen to expect an array.

Comment: A similar approach with ES6 destructuring: `calledFunction = function(...args) {
  var [num, ...res] = args;
  forwardFunction(...res);
}`

Comment: I created a simple JsFiddle for those that want to play with ..args: 
https://jsfiddle.net/MadCodeMonkey/ew9n3uxh/

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use another function to do it, you can use `.slice()`:

```
    forwardFunction([].slice.call(arguments, 1));
```

Now, that passes an *array* to "forwardFunction". If you want to pass all the arguments except the first as distinct separate arguments, you'd have to use `.apply()`:

```
    forwardFunction.apply(undefined, [].slice.call(arguments, 1));
```

For heavily-used functions that need to use their arguments in a call to another function, however, it's better to *carefully* use a simple loop to copy the arguments into an array:

```
    var a = [];
    for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; ++i)
      a[i] = arguments[i];
    forwardFunction(a); // or forwardFunction.apply(null, a);
```

(Note that that loop skips the first argument.) If the `arguments` object is passed as a parameter to another function, then the calling function generally cannot be optimized. Sometimes that's not a big deal, but it's important to know for the times when it is.

See also the destructuring assignment approach in sdgluck's answer. I don't know whether that causes optimization problems; I sort-of doubt it but then I'm not sure how mature the ES2015 code is in the optimizing runtime systems of the world.

Comment: But your first example will pass an array, not a series of arguments (assuming that's what the OP wants, granted his question indicates the possiblity that he thinks `forwardFunction` **should** be passed an array-like).

Comment: @torazaburo well it's not clear what the OP wants to do; it's not stipulated. I'll expand the answer.

Comment: The destructuring assignment **is** likely to degrade optimizability  because under the sheets it is most likely being transpiled into calls to some run-time routine. Even after being supported natively, given the current limitations, I'd be surprised if it didn't continue to exclude functions from being optimized.

Comment: @torazaburo well apparently, in V8 at least, code that only references the `.length` and indexed properties of `arguments` is still optimizable. It seems like it's at least possible for `[...arguments]` to satisfy that, but who knows. (Well I guess the V8 people know :)

Comment: Yes, i would like to forward a series of arguments not an array.

Comment: Calling `forwardFunction([...arguments].slice(1)`, Node 5/V8 reports `[disabled optimization for 0x30329121 <SharedFunctionInfo calledFunction>, reason: Spread in array literal]`.

Comment: huh. Shows how much I know about V8 runtime internals :)

Answer (score 2):

ES5:

```
forwardFunction(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
```

ES6:

```
forwardFunction([...arguments].slice(1));
```

Comment: I've been trying to find any reference that indicates whether a destructuring assignment like that causes problems for optimization. It doesn't *seem* like it would. It's certainly nice-looking :)

Comment: Sure, but why not destructure right in the parameters?

Comment: @torazaburo I don't know... I didn't think of that? ;-)